# Private Variable Compile Error: Variable is Private

Tags: c++, private

I have the following code:

```
class Point{
private:

    double x, y;
public:
    Point(){
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;

    }
//...
};
```

I am getting an error on the private declaration of doubles x and y:

```
'double Point::y' is private
```

My code works fine when I rearrange it as:

```
class Point{
//private:
public:

    double x, y;
    //public:
    Point(){
       this->x = 0;
       this->y = 0;

    }   
//...
};
```

But obviously then double isn't private. If no private keyword is given and the doubles are declared before the public keyword, I get the same private variable error.

What am I doing wrong / how can I declare private variables properly? 
Thanks!

I have error makers in eclipse both within the class and at the declaration of the doubles: (I placed an X in the code since I can't post screen shots)

```
class Point{
private:
//public:

    X double x, y;
    X Point(): x{0},y{0}{
}
```

SOLVED: Thanks to Dieter Lücking for point out that in my example I forgot to uncomment the public keyword when I provided a full code example. Further along in my code I had written:

```
cout << "\nPoint sum: " << e.x + e.getY();
```

This, oddly, caused errors to appear both on the cout line, as well as the declaration line, which is what caused my confusion. Fixing the cout line:

```
cout << "\nPoint sum: " << e.x + e.getY();
```

Solved all the errors. Thank you all!

Comment: I recommend you start using constructor initializer lists.

Comment: By that do you mean?:
 `Point(): x{0},y{0}{

 }`

Comment: I don't believe you get the error on declaration. Your code will compile fine. Check the code you did not post here. Somewhere you access x and y, this is where you get problems.

Comment: @iceburg, Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Are you doing something along the lines of `Point x; x.y = 42;`?

Comment: I've posted my full code. I believe I have tried to privately access (Like faranwrath's `Point x; x.y = 42;`), but that doesn't mean I should get an error in the declaration line, should it?

I'm also getting errors in my getX() function inside my Point class... =/

Comment: In the full code all is private

Comment: Note: Two points may describe a (finite) line but no mathematical vector (a vector has no 'location')

Comment: Perhaps check the details of the error messages?  You posted part of it, but not the part that says what file/line is reporting the error.

Comment: @Dieter: AH! That's it! Once I did that I only had 2 errors. I'll update my question. Thanks!

Comment: GCC, for one, will tell you that something is trying to access it and point you to that spot, but on the next line, say something like `declared here` and point you to where it's declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing to notice is that in your `main` function you try to access `x` and `y` directly instead of using the accessor functions `getX()` and `getY()`.

Another thing is that (probably due to recent editing) all of your member functions in `Point` are `private`. Just uncomment the `//public:` line directly before the c'tor.

Comment: I don't see any accessor functions `getX` and `getY` declared.

Comment: They're declared and defined inside the full code sample.

Comment: @OP: As an aside, I find the name `getSin` ridiculous, compared to just `sin`, the name known from mathematics. Similarly, one has `std::string::length`, not `std::string::getLength`. And so on. For in general, in C++ a `get` prefix only contributes negatively, with verbosity. In some very few cases it can be useful, but mostly, its contribution is negative (as opposed to the situation in e.g. Java, which supports introspection).

Answer (score 1):

The code shown at the time of writing this answer isn't the problem.

The compiler complains about some other code accessing `private` members of a `Point` instance.

For a simple `Point` class, with no special class invariant, making the members public is a good idea, but note that *in general* it's *not* a good idea.

---

Since you have x and y members of type `double`, note that at least some not-very-long-ago version of Visual C++ had problems optimizing expressions involving such values accessed via accessor methods in a derived class. I don't know why. But it's an addition practical reason to make those members public.

Comment: Thanks. I have contrived the whole program just to familiarize myself with C++, and so the point class is rather.. pointless. But I do want to properly be able to declare some vars private. Would code that wrongly tries to access the private variable elsewhere trigger errors in the variable's declaration?

Comment: it would cause some compilation error (diagnostic), yes

Comment: I would think it would cause compile errors at the line that wrongly accesses, but didn't think it'd cause compile errors at declaration as well... Good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: @iceburg: no, it won't cause compile error at declaration. only at the point of attempted access. sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `templateTestSum()` you are accessing the private members `x` and `y` of `point`:

```
cout << "\nPoint sum: " << e.x + e.y;
```

This is not allowed.